# Django "duplicate key value violates unique constraint" because of the save method

Tags: django, postgresql, model

I am trying to update an existing instance from a model in Django admin interface but I'm getting `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint` because of the save method.
According to the documentation, the save method should not have any problems UPDATING the model. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert .

> Django abstracts the need to use INSERT or UPDATE SQL statements.
> Specifically, when you call save() and the object’s primary key
> attribute does not define a default, Django follows this algorithm:
>
> If the object’s primary key attribute is set to a value that evaluates
> to True (i.e., a value other than None or the empty string), Django
> executes an UPDATE. If the object’s primary key attribute is not set
> or if the UPDATE didn’t update anything (e.g. if primary key is set to
> a value that doesn’t exist in the database), Django executes an
> INSERT.

Now this is my model and the save method:

```
class Examene(models.Model):
    saptamani = models.IntegerField(default=3, validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)])
    zile = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=True)
    profesor = models.ForeignKey(Materii_profesor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    materii = models.ManyToManyField(Materie)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.zile = (self.saptamani * 5)
        super(Examene, self).save(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

I am using Postgres as database, how would I avoid the error? Is there a way to delete existing instance from the save method and save the updated version? Or is another way to pass this? I'm having the same problem for all the models that have override the save method.

Comment: You don't need to pass `self` to the super save method.

Comment: I know, I tried to add it because I someone suggested I should, but it doesn't work without it either.